# R function error for RHS replacement of missing values

Tags: r, function, missing-data

First mystery is why a character vector in a csv-file with empty cells does not include NAs. Instead they appear as "". Tried e.g. `read.csv(file, na.strings = "")`, but failed.

Regardless, the question is why this function returns an error, while it works outside the function.

```
clean.data <- function(dta, col) {
  dta$col[dta$col == ""]  <- NA # set empty cells to missing
}
```

Something obvious is wrong, but I can't see it.

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "col", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 20692
```

Comment: Use  `dta[dta[, col] == "", col]  <- NA`

Comment: Ah briefly why? It works, btw.

Comment: Because `$` isn't intended for programmatic use like this. You can't pass it a character for column selection.

Comment: @Roland can I just ask whether this works also in a function? Tried with `replace.empty <- function(dta, col) {
  dta[dta[, col] == "", col] <- NA }` but not working.

Comment: Your function needs to return something. Try `function(dta, col) { dta[dta[, col] == "", col] <- NA; dta }`

Comment: That only returns the data hence not what I want. maybe something more fundamental is wrong in my code/data...

Comment: I assumed you want to return the data with `""` replaced with `NA`?

Comment: yes that's it but I see no changes by running the function.

Comment: This is working `gov[gov[, last_modified] == "", last_modified]`, but this is not `gov[gov[, last_modified] == "", last_modified] <- NA` and returns `Error in [<-.data.table(*tmp*, gov[, last_modified] == "", last_modified,  : 
  object 'last_modified' not found` I find it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first problem: `''` is not the same as `NA` . The latter has a specific meaning in `R`; it's a particular type of nondefined nothingness.  Example:

```
> 'foo'==''
[1] FALSE
> 'foo'==NA
[1] NA
```

You can perform logical and other operations on `''` but almost any operation involving `NA` returns `NA` by design.